# Prime ideals and localisation of the global section ring of the structure sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $(X, \mathcal O_X)$ be a Noetherian scheme. Let $A=\mathcal O_X(X)$ be the global section ring. For every $x\in X$, let $\mathfrak m_x$ be the unique maximal ideal of the local ring $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ .

I have two questions:

(1) Let $x\in X$ and $j_x: A \to \mathcal O_{X,x}$ be the natural ring homomorphism. Consider the prime ideal $P_x=j_x^{-1} (\mathfrak m_x)$ of $A$. Is it true that $A_{P_x}  \cong \mathcal O_{X,x}$ as rings ?  (If this is not true in general, is it at least true when $x$ is a closed point ?) Is it at least true under some additional hypothesis on $X$ ?

(2) With notation as in (1), we have a function $h: X \to $ Spec $(A)$ defined as $h(x)=P_x$ . Is $h$ continuous ? Is it injective ? Is it surjective ? What happens if we restrict $h$ only on the closed points of $X$ ?

Note that for affine schemes the answer to both question is yes (and basically the map $h$ in (2) is the identity map) .

In general $h$ need not be injective since for say $X=\mathbb P^n_k$, where $k$ is a field, $\mathcal O(X)=k$ ...

Comment: For integral scheme $X$ affine implies that $Frac(O_X(X))$ is the whole function field. For non-integral domains the kernels from the ring to its localizations can be non-empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, this is not true, not even for closed points. Consider $\Bbb P^1_k$. Then $A=k$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1_k,pt}\cong k[t]_{(t)}$, and $j^{-1}$ of the maximal ideal is the zero ideal, so the requested localization of $A$ is just $A$, which is very far from $k[t]_{(t)}$. Certainly this will be an isomorphism if $X$ is quasiaffine - I don't see other good/easy conditions to add here which give you the same result.
2. Yes, this is continuous - it's actually a morphism of schemes (locally on affine patches of $X$ it's specified by the inclusion of the global sections ring in to the ring of regular functions on that affine). It cannot be guaranteed to be either injective or surjective. You've already identified that it's not injective by the case of $\Bbb P^n_k$. To show it's not surjective, consider $\Bbb A^2_k$ with the origin removed. It's well known that this has ring of global functions $k[x,y]$, and the map $h:\Bbb A^2_k\setminus\{(0,0)\}\to \Bbb A^2_k$ is the natural inclusion, which misses the origin.

This map is often called the affinization map, if you're looking to search for more information about it.

Comment: The point of considering $\Bbb{A}^2_k\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is because $(x,y) \mapsto [x:y]$ is a morphism to $\Bbb{P}^1_k$ which doesn't extend to $\Bbb{A}^2_k$.

Comment: What? No, it's because it's the first example of Hartog's that you meet. Regular functions extending over missing points makes the affinization map not surjective, which is what matters in this question.

Comment: "Removing a point" is something concrete : (in dimension $\ge 2$) it doesn't add any function but it adds new morphisms to projective spaces. If there wasn't such morphisms there would be no reason to delete just a point.

Comment: So if I'm not mistaken, my map $h$ is the same as the canonical map $X \to$ Spec $\mathcal O(X)$ which corresponds,via the natural identification, to the identity map in Hom$(\mathcal O(X), \mathcal O(X))(=$ Hom$(X,$ Spec $\mathcal O(X))$ ) ... this affinization map is a quasi-compact open immersion when $X$ is quasi-affine, https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01P5, Lemma 27.18.4. ... so when $X$ is Quasi-affine, is my question (1) true ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct and what I meant to type. I've edited the post.

Comment: Basically, to have the localisations of the global section ring match with the stalks of the scheme, we just only need that the canonical map $X \to$ Spec $\mathcal O(X)$ be an open immersion ... is there a characterisation of such (Noetherian, separated) schemes ? $X$ quasi-affine also says that the canonical map is also quasi-compact , so I think $X$ being quasi-affine , although is sufficient, is not really necessary ...

Comment: I don't know of good characterizations for this. The problem is that this condition can't be local on $X$, which most nice properties we like are.